# Loop macro: Parentheses in the using subclause

Tags: loops, common-lisp, hashtable, language-design, practical-common-lisp

[Chapter 22](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) of Practical Common Lisp explains (among other things) how to use both the keys and the values when iterating through a hash table with the `loop` macro:

```
(loop for k being the hash-keys in h using (hash-value v) ...)
```

The explanation is concluded with the following footnote:

> Don't ask me why `LOOP`'s authors chickened out on the no-parentheses style for the `using` subclause.

That's perfectly fine for the book and I don't blame Peter Seibel for not knowing it. Still, I am somewhat curious about the reasons for this design decision of. Why isn't the syntax something like

```
(loop for k being the hash-keys in h using hash-value v ...)
```

Is it easier to parse? Or is there some deeper reason behind it?